# Map the key and the value of HashTable(System.Collection) to a custom property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mapping

I have a HashTable(System.Collection) and a custom property.

The default value of "_sendToDb" should be false, I will change this  later in the Grid of my wpf-program.

This is what I have:

My Hashtable:

```
Hashtable hsh = new Hashtable();
```

My property:

```
public class ImagesFromFS : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string _value;
    string _path;
    bool _sendToDb;

   ...

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return _path;
        }

        set
        {
            _path = value;
            onPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public bool SendToDb
    {
        get
        {
            return _sendToDb;
        }

        set
        {
            onPropertyChanged();
            _sendToDb = value;
        }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }

        set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The final goal should be, binding my new created property to the gridView.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you putting in the Hashtable? And why are you referring to a Hashtable having both keys and values in your title? (they only have values).

Comment: You should be using a `Dictionary`, not a `HashTable` as of 2006 when .NET 2.0 came out.

Comment: @Atoms No, they have both keys and values.

Comment: @Servy Bah, totally confused myself with Hashset.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Convertor for this purpose. which return path according to the value passed to it.

Here is demo of a basic convertor modify it according to your need. It have both methods Convert or ConvertBack. Hope it will help. :)

```
public class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((int)value)
        {
            case 1:
                return "Raised";
            case 2:
                return "Work in Progress";
            case 3:
                return "Resolved";
            case 4:
                return "Closed";
            default:
                return "undefined";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value.ToString())
        {
            case "Raised":
                return 1;
            case "Work in Progress":
                return 2;
            case "Resolved":
                return 3;
            case "Closed":
                return 4;
            default: 
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```